# Spatial relationships, geometry and simultaneous equations.

Tags: geometry

I have two rectangles and 16 measurements, from each of the 4 corners of one rectangle to each of the 4 corners of the second.

I do not know, the sizes of the rectangles;nor their anglular relationship.

It is possible to the determine the sizes and relative positions of the two rectangles from the information I have?

This NOT TO SCALE diagram shows the information I have

[image]

(though looking at those again, I think that some of the measurements are suspect. I'll need to re-measure (laborious!); but I think that my question remains valid as it is a method that I am seeking, not a solution to this particular set of values. I have many such relationships to determine from similar information.)

Comment: Is the given array representative of the exact information ? Let me be clearer with an example : are vertex $A$ and vertex $B$ able to certify that it is the **very same** vertex (i.e., 1) which is situated at $87m$ and $112m$ resp. (Btw: Is it an application with acoustic sensors ?). Are the rectangles always non intersecting ? Do you have some limitations on their sizes ?

Comment: The measurements are to the nearest integer; no greater precision is available. The rectangles are always non-intersecting.

Answer (score 3):

**Modified answer** which is no longer an answer "per se" but establishes that the issue is equivalent to a mapping from a right triangle to another right triangle (associated with the fact that the $4 \times 4$ table contains a lot of redundant information).

See "A toy-example with exact distances" at the bottom.

Let us assume WLOG that the first rectangle $R$, with vertices $A,B,C,D$ is fixed with vertices :

$$A=M_1(a,0), \ B=M_2(a,b), \  C=M_3(0,b), \ D= M_4(0,0)$$

Let $M_0$ be the point of the second rectangle $R'$ denoted by $1$ in the array you give, i.e., with the following resp. distances to points $M_1,... M_4$ :

$$d_{01}=87, \ d_{02}=112, \ d_{03}=117, \ d_{04}=103\ $$

Consider the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) set to $0$ which expresses a constraint between the mutual distances of 5 points:

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&d_{01}^{2}&d_{02}^{2}&\cdots &d_{04}^{2}&1\\d_{01}^{2}&0&d_{12}^{2}&\cdots &d_{14}^{2}&1\\d_{02}^{2}&d_{12}^{2}&0&\cdots &d_{24}^{2}&1\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots \\d_{04}^{2}&d_{14}^{2}&d_{24}^{2}&\cdots &0&1\\1&1&1&\cdots &1&0\end{vmatrix}=0$$

giving the general determinant,

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&p&q&r&s&1\\p&0&b^{2}&(a^2+b^2)&a^2 &1\\q&b^{2}&0&a^2 &(a^2+b^2)&1\\ 
r&(a^2+b^2)&a^{2}&0&b^2&1\\ 
s&a^2&(a^2+b^2)&b^{2}&0&1\\ 
1&1&1&1&1&0\end{vmatrix}=0\tag{1}$$

(here with $p=87^2, \ q=112, \ r=117^2, \ s=103^2$).

The astonishing thing (I hadn't foreseen it) is that the expansion of (1) gives plainly:

$$4a^2b^2(p-q+r-s)=0\tag{2}$$

As $a \ne 0, \ b \ne 0$, one must have

$$p-q+r-s=0\tag{3}$$

which means that on a same row of the $4 \times 4$ array, **the sum of the squares of the first and the third element is necessarily equal to the sum of the squares of the second and the fourth**. For example, in the first row $87,112,117,103$  : $87^2+117^2=?=112^2+103^2$ (which in fact differ by a certain amount : $21258 \ne 23153$). The same for the other rows. The same property is also valid for the columns (by symmetry!). As a consequence, these $4 \times 4 = 16$ values are redundant : there are only $3 \times 3=9$ independent parameters. We will choose to restrict our attention to the $3 \times 3$ upper left block.

As a consequence, the problem is equivalent to work on the mutual distances of $A,B,C$ vs. $A',B',C'$ where for example $(A,\vec{AB},\vec{AC})$ or $(B,\vec{BA}, \vec{BC})$ or ... and $(A',\vec{A'B'},\vec{A'C'})$ or $(B',\vec{B'A'}, \vec{B'C'})$ or ... are orthogonal bases ($3!=6 $ possible matches).

---

**Towards a solution** [A paragraph I will attempt to improve in the coming days, written, especialy at the end, in an informal way].

1. Take one of the six possible matchings, for example $(B,\vec{BA}, \vec{BC})$ that has to be placed in correspondance with : $(A',\vec{A'B'},\vec{A'C'})$ (it means that in this case, in right triangles $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ we assume that the right angles are in $B$ and $A'$ resp.). [of course, one must visit all the 6 possible matchings].
2. Let (x,y) and (x',y') the coordinate systems associated with resp. bases $(B,\vec{BA}, \vec{BC})$ and $(A',\vec{A'B'},\vec{A'C'})$

There must exist parameters $\theta, e, f, g, h$ such that one base is mapped onto the other by means of this affin transform:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}}_{X'}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta&-\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta&\ \ \ \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}}_R \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\ 0&b\end{pmatrix}}_S\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}}_X+\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}}_T$$

Where $R$, $S$, $T$, account resp. for Rotation, Scaling and translation (rotation is important to preserve orthogonality).

Therefore, using the $3 \times 3$ array mentionned above, one can write 9 equations in these five unknowns ; here is one for example

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} \ \text{is mapped onto} \ \begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta + c\\a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta + d\end{pmatrix}$$

and we equate two ways of expressing the squared  distance :

$$(a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta + c - 1)^2+(a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta + d-0)^2=93^2$$

Of course, if there is a solution (1 solution only for one of the 6 pairings to be considered), 5 equations (the number of parameters) are in principle enough, and one checks afterwards that the remaining constraints are verified.

Which method of resolution of these 5 equations ? Newton iteration by default... But I must work on examples...

---

**A toy-example with exact distances**

Consider the following two rectangles (the second one being plainly a square :-))

[image]

with the following $4 \times 4$ table of mutual **squared** distances:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&A&B&C&D\\ \hline
1&5&13&17&\color{red}{9}\\
2&1&5&5&\color{red}{1}\\
3&16&26&20&\color{red}{10}\\
4&\color{red}{20}&\color{red}{34}&\color{red}{32}&\color{red}{18}
\end{array}$$

on which we check (property (3)) that on the first line $1-5+13-9=0$, on the second line $1-5+5-1=0$, etc., on the first column $5-1+16-20=0$, etc. explaining why red-colored entries are redundant.

Comment: I can give more precisions if necessary.

Comment: After several readings, I think I can get what I need from your reply. It may take me a while; its somewhat over my head. Thanks.

Comment: In fact I just discovered an unexpected constraint : in a same line, for example, in the first row $87,112,117,103$ one must have the sum of the squares of the first and the third equal to the sum of the squares of the second and the fourth : $87^2+117^2=?=112^2+103^2$ (which is not the case by a certain amount $21258 \ne 23153$). The same for the other rows. And therefore the same for the columns (by symmetry!). As a consequence,  there are only $3 \times 3=9$ independent parameters instead of $4 \times 4=16$. I am going to modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thankyou for the "toy example".Exactly what I needed. Math formalism gives my a** a headache :) There is a truism in programming -- my moderately successful, life-long passion and career that any (programming) problem can be solved with one more level of indirection. Unfortunately, the human brain can only handle 3-4 levels of indirection at a time. (formal) Mathematicians will happily construct 2 more levels of (notational) indirection to save typing 1 extra character per reference. #DrivesMeNuts#

Comment: I appreciate 1) that you have appreciated my example. 2) your humour. I thank you for this interesting question that I will continue to think about. btw, you haven't said the framework in which you have to solve such an issue ? I was wondering if it was with acoustic sensors because I had once to help somebody on such issues.

Comment: "I was wondering if it was with acoustic sensors"; No. I am trying to map the layout of buildings in a sniper game. The "bad guys" stand on rooftops and run from corner to corner; and if I shoot them from my rooftop, I get a measure of the distance of the "hit". No other measurements are possible. I hope you do not feel cheated that 'interesting math' derives from such a trivial source.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. About your last sentence, not at all "cheated": I am, in a visceral way, an applied mathematician ! And games are often very "triggering" for people like us.

Comment: And sorry again for the mathematical jargon... (I will remember the very good expression "adding supplementary levels of indirection" !)